# Setting path to image source in reactnative

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

```
<Image
          source={require(`../${item.image}`)}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.cardImg}
                     
   />
```

local images folder path  =>  ../media/products/four.jpg

api response =>   "image":"media/products/four.jpg",

I want to render {item.image} but can't access the local images folder path.

Comment: Seems api is returning the path with a slash after products whereas it should be a dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Please use following type for that

source={{uri:BaseUrl+item.image}}

Thank You